# vscode keyboard shortcut for mouse click new file

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there vscode keyboard shortcut that gives me the same result as you mouse click the new file icon at the top of your working folder? Ctr+N gives me a new text file I have to rename with my preferred extension double the work. no use why I want a text file? say I want html file or js file mouse click on the new file icon gives me a box to type in the preferred type of my file. that's perfect. Does shortcut mean speedup same thing right? why Microsoft programmers program the Ctr+n shortcut to give me a totally different result than mouse click new file? Isn't that the better way? I am frustrated, waste a hell lot of time searching google without luck finding a shortcut to do this simple task. the mouse click is saving time than this :-) then I see in the file menu another shortcut Cnt+Alt+Windows+N to create so I tried that. it gives me box to type not the same way as a mouse click though it's on the top. finally, another way I thought and type index.html to create a new Html file but nothing happened it vanishing . in that shortcut if you type anything into it and enter then it vanishing but if you just enter blank its creates a default new text file. same result as Ctr+N .

I simply want a keyboard shortcut for this mouse click show on the picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z738e.jpg)

Comment: is your OS screen capture of such a poor quality

Comment: rioV8 I cant use the snipping tool to capture an exact picture while the mouse pointer their and textbox open so its a poor picture  taken from a phone

Comment: use the Print Screen button and a simple edit program to crop the snapped image

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.